# Space carving of tetrahedra

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

I have been reading this paper http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_iccv_workshops_2013/W21/papers/Sugiura_3D_Surface_Extraction_2013_ICCV_paper.pdf

I have already generated a tetrahedra for my mesh and I would like to create a surface mesh. I can't understand the algorithm. From my understanding, there is a camera that generates rays towards to the points of the tetrahedral, and I get the intersections, but how would I eliminate the triangles that are inside or outside ? how would I detect inside or outside polygons ?

Would someone give a pseudo code of the algorithm ?

Comment: Lookup "triangle winding order"

Comment: Why downvoting ?!

Comment: @RichardCritten Can you elaborate more ? What's triangle winding order related to simplifying the mesh construction ?

Comment: When your ray intersects a triangle the winding order of the edges that make up the triangle determine whether the triangle is a front or back face.  This is basic 3D geometry maybe you should do some background reading.

Comment: @RichardCritten and when its front or back face, how to extract a surface from that mesh based on the winding order ? should I ignore back faces ? cull them ?